# Type error with the use of transactional memory

Tags: haskell, tvar

I am using Transaction variables in haskell that I instantiate in a function and collect in a list and that I give to another function to write values in:

```
step player ghosts info = do let unblocked = allPaths (source info) (target info) (graph info)
                         buff <- atomically $ newTVar [[]]
                         atomically $ put buff unblocked
                         let create  = do return newGhostVal
                         let ghosts' = zip (map (\g -> newGhostVal) ghosts) ghosts

                         mapM_ (\g -> forkIO(atomically $ moveGhost buff (fst g) (graph info) (snd g))) ghosts'
                         putStrLn "launched"
```

and I use these shared variables (stored in ghosts') in the function moveGhost:

```
moveGhost buff res graph ghost =
             do notBlocked <- get buff
             ...
             writeTVar buff notBlocked'
             writeTVar res (Just ghost'')
             return()
```

While I use the same strategy for both shared variables buff as res, I get an error for the use of `Tvar res`:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `TVar (Maybe Ghost)'
            with actual type `STM (TVar (Maybe a0))'
Expected type: [(TVar (Maybe Ghost), Ghost)]
  Actual type: [(STM (TVar (Maybe a0)), b0)]
In the second argument of `mapM_', namely ghosts'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  mapM_
    (\ g
       -> forkIO
            (atomically $ moveGhost buff (fst g) (graph info) (snd g)))
    ghosts'
```

Does anybody know what the problem is with this TVar and why it isn't a problem for TVar buff?

Comment: I think we'd need to see `newGhostVal` to be precise about what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that these are values in a list, I would expect that `[TVar (Maybe Ghost)']` is the correct type--that is, a list of `TVar`s--and that you have `[STM (TVar (Maybe a0))']` instead because you're creating a list of `STM` actions that *would* create `TVar`s, but not actually using that inside a transaction.

So, wherever you have that list of `TVar`-creating actions, you'll want to do something like `sequence` to turn that into `STM [(TVar (Maybe a0))']`, a single action that creates a list of `TVar`s, then either bind that inside a transaction (i.e., using `<-` instead of `let`) or use `atomically` as well to create the `TVar`s in `IO`. Either way, the result of binding that value will be the list of `TVar`s that you probably want.